# java - access incremented static variable from another class

Tags: java, android, static, static-members

I have a static variable and updating it's value in class. But when i access this variable from another class , it shows unupdated value.

CLASS A

```
  public static int postID = 1;

  public static String Creator()
  {
    String message = "POST id="+postID;
    return message;
  }

  void updatePostID()
  {
      postID++; //this function is being called each 10 seconds
  }

  @Override
  public void start() { 
    handler.post(show);
  }

  Handler handler = new Handler();
  private final Runnable show = new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        ...
               updatePostID();
               handler.postDelayed(this, 10000);    
    }
  };
```

CLASS B

```
  String message = A.Creator(); //this always prints postID as 1 all time
```

I need a global variable that i can access from each class and update its value. Waiting for your help (I am using this with a Android Service)

Comment: this is not even valid java syntax

Comment: What is function work()? That's not even valid input?!

Comment: it is just an example.. i mean that i am updating it's value in a function

Comment: Well write out your exact code that you are using - after all, it's a fairly short amount of code

Comment: I'm assuming btw that you ARE calling the work method?

Comment: @dracula: Where and when are you calling the updatePostID() function?

Comment: The static variable is not getting updated when a) you did not call `updatePostID` - probably `A.Creator()` called too early b) the app was killed in between so the static variable is initialized to 1 again c) in rare cases when you use multiple threads and one thread modifies while another thread reads - you are not guaranteed that the other thread can see the change unless you make the variable `volatile`.

Comment: I am sure that A.Creator is being called after updatePostID.In debug mode , when breakpoint is in Creator() function from class A , it gives 5 , when breakpoint comes to Creator() class again which class B calls , it gives 1.

Answer (score 2):

this is a tested code .

```
public class A {

    public static int id = 0;

    public static int increment(){
        return A.id++;
    }

}

public class B {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.println(A.increment());
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: @dracula: Yes it does. Are you sure you've copied that code over exactly?

Comment: add volatile to public static int postID = 1;

Answer (score 1):

You need to call work to execute `id++;`

```
class B {

    public static void main(String... args){

        A a = new A();
        a.work(); // You need to call it to apply add operation

        System.out.println(A.id); // Prints 1

    }

}
```

And this is a sample class A:

```
class A {

    static int id = 0;

    public void work(){

        id++;

    }
}
```

Save class A in a file named A.java and class B in a file named B.java.

Then compile B. Since B creates an instance of class A, A will be compiled and you don't need to compile A separately-

> javac B.java

After compilation, to execute/run-

> java B

Answer (score 1):

class A
   {
    static int id=0;

```
//I am updating id in my function ,
{
  id++;
 }
}
```

public class StartingPoint  {

```
public static void main(String... args){

    A a = new A();
    A b = new A();

    System.out.println(A.id);
    System.out.println(a.id);
}
```

}

Comment: I think you need to review your code. This does not do what you intend it to do - why are you creating two objects of class A, then referencing it statically (and the static block is horrible! Put it in a method).

Comment: Just a counter example, it will increase value each time you create a new instance

Comment: You haven't explained that though. Additionally, it's very counter-intuitive to increase the int by creating new objects of the class when the objects aren't used and the int is accessed statically.

Answer (score 0):

Sajal Dutta's answer explains it perfectly, but if you want to keep it ALL static (i.e. not create any objects of class A, you could modify the code slightly to this:

```
class A {
    static int id = 0;
    public static void work(){
        id++;
    }
}
```

Then:

```
class B {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println(A.id);
        A.work();
        System.out.println(A.id);
    }
}
```

This would produce:

> 0
>   1

**Edit (with regard to your updated question)**

Where are you *specifying* the update of the static int? From the code you've provided all you will do is print out the same int over and over as the method containing the increment process is never called.

**Edit 2:**

Try this:

Change:

```
handler.post(show);
```

to:

```
handler.postDelayed(show, 10000);
```

Comment: As i wrote in comments , i am calling updatePostID() with a handler that run each 10 seconds.

Comment: There is not any problem with handler. You understand my problem. If i access postID in Class A it gives me incremented value , if call it from Class B it gives 1 , but it is 5 normally (just an example)